# Accessing Cloud storage bucket in a java SDK Apache Beam pipeline yields 401 Invalid credentials

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, apache-beam-io

I'm trying to read a csv from a cloud storage bucket and store it in a pcollection. To authenticate with the bucket, I'm using a service account with **roles/storage.admin** and a JSON key. This my pipelinesOptions object.

```
DataflowPipelineOptions dfOptions = PipelineOptionsFactory.as(DataflowPipelineOptions.class);
        dfOptions.setProject("project_name");
        dfOptions.setStagingLocation("bucket_name");
        dfOptions.setGcpCredential(GoogleCredentials.fromStream(
        new FileInputStream(PATH_TO_JSON_KEY)));
        dfOptions.setTempLocation("gs://bucket_name/folder_name");
        dfOptions.setServiceAccount("serivce_acount_name");
        Pipeline myPipe= Pipeline.create(dfOptions);
        PCollection<ReadableFile> readFile= myPipe.apply( FileIO.match().filepattern("gs://bucket_name/file_name.csv")).apply(FileIO.readMatches());
```

However, running the above mentioned pipeline results in the error:

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Error trying to get gs://bucket_name/object_name.csv: {"code":401,"errors":[{"domain":"global","location":"Authorization","locationType":"header","message":"Invalid Credentials","reason":"authError"}],"message":"Invalid Credentials"}
```

If I use the dataflowrunner instead by adding to my Pipelineoptions

```
dfOptions.setRunner(DataflowRunner.class);
```

I get the same exact error for my staging bucket.

```
401 Unauthorized
GET https://storage.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/bucket_name
{
  "code" : 401,
...same as above...
}
```

I'm using the same credentials to access the same bucket GCS Java client library and it works absolutely fine.

```
StorageOptions options = StorageOptions.newBuilder()
                        .setProjectId(PROJECT_ID)
                       .setCredentials(GoogleCredentials.fromStream(
                    new FileInputStream(PATH_TO_JSON_KEY))).build();
    
Storage storage = options.getService();
Blob blob = storage.get(BUCKET_NAME, OBJECT_NAME);
ReadChannel r = blob.reader();
```

I also downloaded the same file from the same bucket with same Service account and key using **gsutil** with no problems. The problem only occurs when using Apache beam.

Versions of various dependencies I'm using-

- Apache Beam 2.24
- google-cloud-storage 2.11.3
- google-cloud-dataflow-java-sdk-all 2.5.0
- google-api-client 1.35.1

Comment: You want to run your job from your local machine ?

Comment: I have tried both ways, local and Datflow but I'm getting stuck on the same step, which is interacting with the cloud storage buckets.

Comment: If you set `export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` from the shell of your local machine, no need to set it in the code of your `Dataflow` job. Is it mandatory now for you to store your Service account token in `GCS` ?

Comment: @MazlumTosun Using GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS in the environment works however I need to set it in the dataflow job itself.

Comment: Have you tried to use the ˋ—serviceAccount` option ?

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/concepts/security-and-permissions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is worth noting that Dataflow's support for Apache Beam 2.24.0 was [deprecated on September 18, 2021](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/support/sdk-version-support-status). A first step I would say is to update to a recent version of the SDK. In particular, Beam has adopted the GCP Libraries BOM which coordinates the versions of GCP client libraries and auth libraries.

Comment: I had used the archetype to generate my maven project and assumed that 2.24.0 was the latest version without bothering to check mvn central. My sloppiness has cost me a day, thanks for pointing it out!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of set the service account from the code of `Dataflow` job, you can pass a program argument when launching the job `--serviceAccount` :

example :

```
mvn compile exec:java \
  -Dexec.mainClass=yourApp \
  -Dexec.args=" \
  --project=your_project \
  --serviceAccount=your_account_id@project.gserviceaccount.com
```

You can check from the documentation :

https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/concepts/security-and-permissions

Comment: This should be identical to `dfOptions.setServiceAccount("your_account_id@project.gserviceaccount.com")` assuming the `dfOptions` was parsed from the command line args.